Definition of independence. Does it apply when the existence of a r.v. depends on another r.v.?
Basically my question is, we know the definition of independence has to do with the values of random variables, but does it apply when the existence of a random variable depends on the other?
Suppose I have two dices, one is 4-faced, another 6-faced. I roll the 4-faced dice twice, and if both are 1, I roll this 4-faced dice a third time, otherwise, I roll the 6-faced dice as my third roll.
Now consider all values I get from rolling the 4-faced dice. There may be two values $X_{1}, X_{2}$, or three values $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}$. Are all/both these values independent?
The existence of $X_{3}$ obviously depends on $X_{1}, X_{2}$, but to argue in the definition of independence, we have to consider all events like "$X_{1}=1, X_{2}=4, X_{3}=2$" and see if its probability equals the product of probabilities of "$X_{1}=1$", "$X_{2}=4$", and "$X_{3}=2$".
But when $X_{1}=1, X_{2}=4$, there is no $X_{3}$ so what is the probability of "$X_{1}=1, X_{2}=4, X_{3}=2$"?

Before asking if $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are independent, all three of them have to be defined. Your $X_3$ isn't completely defined; it should have a value for every outcome in your probability space, but it doesn't. So it doesn't make sense to ask the question. You could ask other similar questions instead - but which ones you ask depends on why you want to know if these are independent in the first place.

@MishaLavrov Thanks for your reply. I see what you mean, and I know if $X_{3}$ is simply defined as the value of the third roll (regardless of whether it is the 4-faced or 6-faced dice) then it is well defined. But still considering my original post, if I view the 4-faced dice as a distribution (we may draw 1, 2, 3, and 4 from it), and view each value of a roll as a "sample", can I say all/both samples I got this way are independent?

Why do you want to? Independence isn't something to care about for its own sake; we use independence to simplify calculations later. Depending on what it is you want to do later, you might be able to treat the samples as if they're independent, or you might not.

In your setting, $X_3$ is not independent of $X_1$ and $X_2$. Knowing that $X_1=X_2=1$ has occurred, you know that $X_3=6$ can happen with $\frac{1}{6}$ of the times, i.e., $$\mathbf{P}(X_3=6\mid X_1=X_2=1)=\tfrac{1}{6}.$$ On the other hand, if you know at least one of $X_1$ or $X_2$ is not $1$, then you know that $X_3=6$ is impossible, hence $$\mathbf{P}(X_3=6\mid X_1\neq1\text{ or }X_2\neq1)=0.$$ Since your assessment on the likelihood of $X_3=6$ occurring depends on the information about $X_1$ and $X_2$, we conclude that $(X_1,X_2)$ and $X_3$ are not independent.

@MishaLavrov Actually I was trying to find a rigorous explanation to the sentence "conditional on a particular realization of nt(a), the samples from a are not necessarily independent!" on page 8 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.07272. I don't want to bother you to read it though

We do not, generally, want to say that the existence of a random variable depends on the values of other random variables. A common way to avoid this problem is with a "fictitious continuation" - this is often used in probability to deal with random processes that stop at some point, and in particular reasonable for the multi-armed bandit mentioned in the comment.
Here, we separate the random results of rolling dice from our decision of which dice to roll. We define a potentially-infinite sequence $X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots$ of independent rolls of the $4$-sided die, and a potentially infinite sequence $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, \dots$ of independent rolls of the $6$-sided die. Then, we describe which of these we care about, by additional random variables!
Here, let $N$ be the number of times you end up rolling the $4$-sided die, and let $M$ be the number of times you end up rolling the $6$-sided die. If you use the strategy

I roll the 4-faced dice twice, and if both are 1, I roll this 4-faced dice a third time, otherwise, I roll the 6-faced dice as my third roll.

then we're going to say that if $X_1 = X_2 = 1$, then $N=3$ and $M=0$; otherwise, $N=2$ and $M=1$. This lets us write, for example, $$\sum_{i=1}^N X_i + \sum_{i=1}^M Y_i$$ for the sum of the three rolls we actually end up doing.
Now we can ask: given that $N=2$, are $X_1$ and $X_2$ conditionally independent? Given that $N=3$, are $X_1, X_2, X_3$ conditionally independent?

When $N=2$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not conditionally independent: the conditional distribution of $(X_1, X_2)$ given $N=2$ is sampled uniformly from all $15$ pairs of numbers $1,2,3,4$ that are not $(1,1)$. So, for example, $\Pr[X_1 = 1 \mid N=2] = \frac3{15} = \frac15$, and $\Pr[X_2 = 1 \mid N=2] = \frac15$ as well, but $\Pr[X_1 = 1 \land X_2 = 1 \mid N=2]$ is $0$, not $\frac1{25}$.
Technically, when $N=3$, the three random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are conditionally independent, but for boring reasons: $X_1\mid N=3$ and $X_2 \mid N=3$ are guaranteed to be $1$, and constant random variables are technically independent of everything else. For example, $$\Pr[X_1 = 1 \land X_2 = 1 \land X_3 = 4 \mid N=3] = \frac14$$ and $$\Pr[X_1 = 1 \mid N=3] \cdot \Pr[X_2 =1\mid N=3] \cdot \Pr[X_3 = 4 \mid N=3] = \frac14.$$

This is the sort of calculation the text refers to when saying "conditional on a particular realization of $n_t(a)$, the samples from arm $a$ are not necessarily independent". (The sequences like $X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots$ and $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, \dots$ are what the text later calls "reward tapes".)

This is a very clear explanation! Thank you so much!!!
